# Getting License error while using graphlab.SFrame in iPython notebook even though I am using a valid license key

Tags: python, graphlab

In a Machine Learning Course from Coursera by University of Washington, I am using graphlab library in iPython notebook.

I am trying to execute the below code and getting an error as :

> "InvalidLicense: No JSON object could be decoded"

If I run it after sometime, it gives below error:

> "InvalidLicense: License check failed: Unable to communicate with service. Verify Internet connection and try again or visit https://turi.com/support for support options."

I tried running graphlab.SFrame method on a JSON file as well as a CSV file but it gives the same error.

```
import graphlab
graphlab.product_key.set_product_key('my license key')
sales =graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')
```

When I execute the below code, it does print my license key indicating that its valid.

```
graphlab.product_key.get_product_key()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is this in an Amazon cloud or in a local instance?

For Amazon cloud, the location of your instance is a problem. Change it in the Amazon Console upper right.

For local, check your internet connection and the route.